# About unit definition in numerical computation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, simulations, units, computational-physics

I attend an undergraduate level course of quantum mechanics. I am thinking of computer computation on a quantum mechanical problem. I do not have much experience in numerical computation, so I read some introduction book on it before I start my work. In one book that it explains a idea to user propagator for solving the time dependent Schrodinger equation in terms of potential and kinetic term. Here I list the potential part only to address my question

$$\psi(x, \Delta t) = \exp\left[-i\Delta t V(x)/\hbar\right] \psi(x, 0)$$

In computer, we need to setup grid so all computations are performed on grids. So $x$ is in discrete sites. Here is my question, in some problem, the unit of length is in nanometer, energy is electron volt, but those are not SI units. The computer does not know what's the unit of the grids we create, so when I say x=[-100 -99 -98 ... 0 ... 98 99 100], what is that really refer to? an unitless array?

Besides since $\hbar$ is very small quantity in unit of $J\cdot s$, but potential $V(x)$ is given as eV, x defined in unit of nm and time is in nanosecond. I can convert all those units to J, meter and second but because of tiny $\hbar$, I still get very big number in the exponential. How can I get rid of this? I am so confusing on the unit of $\hbar$, if I want to keep nm, eV and ns, should I convert $\hbar$ to

$$\hbar \to \hbar\times 10^{9}\times \dfrac{1}{1.6\times10^{-19}}\times 10^{18}$$

The first $10^{9}$ convert second to nanosecond, the middle one convert J to eV and the last one convert meter to nanometer.

As pointed out in one of the comment, the SI unit for $\hbar$ is Js, but J could be written in $\mathrm{kg\, m^2/s^2}$, so I multiply it by $10^{18}$ to get $\mathrm{kg \, (nm)^2/s^2}$.

Comment: Often it safer but less convenient to keep everything in SI units.  If you want to use the more convenient units of nm, eV, ns:  note that the units of $\hbar$ are Joule-sec.    The conversion you want is $10^{+9}$ for seconds.  The energy conversion you have is correct.  There is no conversion for meters.

Comment: *Does it sound good* is an opinion question, something that we [don't do here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Thanks garyp. I corrected my question. I add more explanation on how to convert meter to nanometer. But if I do that way, which will make kg m^2/s^2 for J converted to kg (nm)^2/s^2, so is it still good to multiply $(1.6\times10^{-19})^{-1}$ to get eV?

Comment: That's what the gods of information technology gave us IEEE floating point numbers for. Your computer takes care of the order of magnitude for you automatically as soon as you specify a float or (much better!) a double. What you do have to care about are the numerical errors that come from discretization, particularly when you are calculating differences. Those can build up very quickly to O(1), if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing units so your code works well and without jumping back and forth over very large or very small numbers is a bit of an art, but you can pick it up with a bit of practice.

First off: when you say "`x=[-100 -99 -98 ... 0 ... 98 99 100]`", you're not really assigning those values to $x$; instead, you're setting an integer index $n=-100,-99,\ldots,99,100$ which gives you the positions via $x_n=n\,\Delta x$. You do a similar discretization with your timestep $\Delta t$.

On the units side, if you know that $V(x)$ will be in the few-eV range and your timestep $\Delta t$ will be in the few nanosecond regime, then you need to choose an appropriate representation for $\hbar$. In this particular regime, the naive choice is
$$\hbar\approx 6.582×10^{-7}\:\mathrm{eV\,ns}.$$
That's still a pretty small number though. What does this tell you? It mostly says that energy differences in the few-eV range will be much faster than a few nanoseconds; indeed, the fact that 
$$\hbar\approx 0.6582\:\mathrm{eV\,fs}$$
tells you that those dynamics will be in the few-femtosecond regime. If your distances are in multiple nanometers, then the chances are that you're in the solid state with much slower dynamics than that, which means that your energy differences are correspondingly smaller. Thus, choosing a representation like
$$\hbar\approx 0.6582\:\mathrm{meV\,ps}$$
is probably the best.

How do you use such a representation? In your code you will have to calculate phases of the form
$$e^{-i\Delta t \, V(x_n)/\hbar},$$
and eventually you will need to drop the units when you calculate stuff in your code. To do this you just need to be consistent:

```
dt = 1                      // in picoseconds
hbar = 0.6582               // in meV ps
```

For the potential, say you want to describe a function such as $V(x)=(2.475\:\mathrm{meV})\cos(x/15\:\mathrm{nm})$, in which case you'd write

```
V[n] = 2.475 cos(n dx/15)   // in meV
dx = 5                      // in nm
```

Then products of the form `dt V[n]/hbar` are (1) appropriately dimensionless, and correctly scaled (if you've made sure that all the variables are in compatible units!), and (2) do not involve multiplication of very large numbers by very small ones. That's important, because doing that sort of scale jumping can be a good way to waste accuracy.

---

So, finally, how do you actually find the representation you're interested in? I tend to think that units are best handled as independent symbols: $\mathrm{nm}$ is a symbol that stands for a specific length, and saying $L=3\:\mathrm{nm}$ simply says that this one length is three times bigger than this other length.

To take an example, suppose that for whatever reason, the potential will come in [microhartrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree), and we've chosen a timestep in nanoseconds. The product $1\:\mathrm{\mu E_h\:ns}$ is an action, so you can calculate the quotient
$$
\frac{\hbar}{1\:\mathrm{\mu E_h\:ns}}
=\frac{1.054×10^{−34}\mathrm{J\,s}}{10^{-6}×4.359×10^{−18}\:\mathrm{J} × 10^{-9}\mathrm{s}}
=0.0241,
$$
which then means that
$$
\hbar=0.0241\:\mathrm{\mu E_h\:ns}.
$$
Easy!

Comment: Thanks Emilio. It is a good explanation and I follow most of the math here. But I still have one question. Here we define hbar in terms of meV and ps. So everywhere in the computation I should make time in unit of ps, right? If I want the length in unit of nm, I should keep everywhere length has the same unit. Now get back to $\hbar$, SI unit gives J s, but we can break J in terms of kg m^2/s^2, so there is length as well. I am so confusing if we have to take care of the m^2 in $\hbar$ so to have something nm^2 as well? I read your example but I didn't see that conversion.

Comment: You don't "define" ħ in terms of anything - you just *express* it in those units. What matters is that everything is consistent and that the product $\Delta t \,V(x) /\hbar$ does not contain dimensionless but non-unity factors like $1\:\mathrm{eV/J}$ (and not so much a strict "keep all lengths in nm"). In the case of length, note that eV also includes a dimension of length squared, so that's where that goes, but there are extra factors so you do need to be careful.